# How to add a tag cloud on Tumblr?

Tags: tags, blogs, tumblr, tag-cloud

I have been using Tumblr for quite a while but I couldn't figure out how to display the Tumblr tag cloud on the blog.

I would like to ask how to display a tag cloud on my Tumblr blog?

Answer (score 7):

A third-party JavaScript solution: http://rive.rs/projects/tumblr-tag-clouds

> This is a tag cloud generator for Tumblr. It uses the Tumblr API to generate a tag cloud each time your site is accessed.

Another variant (claiming to be faster): http://post-theory.com/tumblr-tag-cloud-javascript

Comment: is there any example code for doing this? I'd like to build my own tag cloud but I'm new to javascript.